# Numpy select checkers pattern to new array

Tags: numpy, scipy, opencv, python

I have a square 2D matrix with odd number of rows and columns. For example

```
11 12 13 14 15
21 22 23 24 25
31 32 33 34 35
41 42 43 44 45
51 52 53 54 55
```

I need to rotate it 45 degrees clockwise and select the maximal square matrix. In this case:

```
13 24 35
22 33 44
31 42 53
```

I can do this in two cycles:

```
new_arr = np.zeros(((orig_range+1)//2, (orig_range+1)//2)
for new_h in range((orig_range+1)//2):
    for new_w in range((orig_range+1)//2):
        old_h = new_h + new_w
        old_w = ((orig_range+1)//2) - new_h + new_w  
        new_arr[new_h, new_w] = orig_arr[old_h, old_w]
```

But this approach is very slow. Rotation in `cv2` is reasonably fast, but the "pixels" don't align well. Forward rotation with sqrt(2) scaling followed by backward rotation with sqrt(2) scaling results in a altered colors of pixels in the center region of the image due to the rounding errors.

What is the efficient way to rotate such a matrix?

Comment: I think I got a solution but can you give me a reproducible example to compare it against? I can't run the upper code block..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Numba's JIT** to drastically speed up the operation, especially by running it in parallel and natively. Moreover, note that the array do not need to be filled with zeros. Here is an untested example:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def compute(orig_range, orig_arr):
    new_arr = np.empty(((orig_range+1)//2, (orig_range+1)//2)
    for new_h in nb.prange((orig_range+1)//2):
        for new_w in range((orig_range+1)//2):
            old_h = new_h + new_w
            old_w = ((orig_range+1)//2) - new_h + new_w  
            new_arr[new_h, new_w] = orig_arr[old_h, old_w]
    return new_arr
```

You can specify the type of the inputs to compile the function ahead of time and so avoid the first call to be significantly slower. This operation should be very fast on array fitting in cache. For big arrays, one can use *tiling* and a different read/write ordering to speed the operation up a bit more.